# Azure Application Insights in API Management - Does it logs Information logged in backend api

Tags: ibm-api-management

I have an existing api developed in asp.net core. It has loggings implemented in it and logging  the information in application insights. I have to deploy the api un api management. I have done that successfully and i have configured my application insights logging in api management.

Should my backend api logs be logged in api management application insights. Should i remove the instrumentation key from app settings of .net core application.

Is there any way to get the backend api logs traced in api management application insights. Do i need to mention the instrumentation key of api management application insights in my .net core api, If yes then what is the point of having api management configured with app insights